# Difference between "-" and "--" prefixed command line parameters?

Tags: command-line, parameter

Scripts on command line offer a wide range of parameters types. Often parameters can be passed to the script via "--[parameter]" or "-[parameter]". But what is the difference? **Why do some parameters have a double "-" and some only a single "-" prefix?** Is there a convention of a technical reason behind this?

Example of possible `git` parameters. (See `--exec-path[=<path>]` vs. `-c name=value`)

```
git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

Comment: also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16339/117549

Comment: @powtac This question may be a duplicate, but it was the first hit google gave when searching for an answer, so I'm glad it was there.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language of the written application. For example in bash you can parse short args (`-`) with both `getopt` and `getopts` and long (`--`) ones with `getopt` only.

`getopts` is a bash function, `getopt` is an separate program. So for maximal portability of your bash scripts, you have to use `getopts` and short notation.

For other languages you can refer to the "parsing arguments" section of the appropriate documentation.

Comment: The OP's example is `git`, which is largely written in C. And it's only one command—with both short and long options.